# Find matching dates between GridViews A & B and auto-tick checkbox in GridView A if theres is match - VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a Gridview that generates the total dates of selected month and displays them in table format, along with a checkbox column.

Said checkbox, when ticked will upload the date, plus additional data from other fields into SQL database. Un-ticking it will delete the data row from the database.

As it is, the GridView cannot remember which row's checkbox was ticked in the last session if I decide to change month or start a new session.

I don't think I can use SQL query to help with that since the GridView content is generated via code and does not use the database. So I made another GridView, this one collects the relevant dates from SQL that have matching information from the additional fields when they were uploaded to database.

My idea was to have the 1st GridView check the data from 2nd GridView and automatically tick the correct checkboxes when it loads.

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ShowBtn.Click

    Call load_Calander()

End Sub

Sub load_Calander()

    '~ code to generate date column in GridView1 ~'
    Dim year As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear.Text)
    Dim month As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Mth_Num.Text)
    If month = 1 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Jan"

    ElseIf month = 2 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Feb"

    ElseIf month = 3 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Mar"

    ElseIf month = 4 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Apr"

    ElseIf month = 5 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "May"

    ElseIf month = 6 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Jun"

    ElseIf month = 7 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Jul"

    ElseIf month = 8 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Aug"

    ElseIf month = 9 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Sep"

    ElseIf month = 10 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Oct"

    ElseIf month = 11 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Nov"

    ElseIf month = 12 Then

        Mth_Txt.Text = "Dec"

    End If

    Dim myList As List(Of [myClass]) = New List(Of [myClass])()

    If month = 1 OrElse month = 3 OrElse month = 5 OrElse month = 7 OrElse month = 8 OrElse month = 10 OrElse month = 12 Then

        For i As Integer = 1 To 31

            Dim item As [myClass] = New [myClass]()
            item.[Date] = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", i.ToString("00"), Mth_Txt.Text, CurrentYear.Text)
            Dim dateValue As DateTime = New DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear.Text), Convert.ToInt32(Mth_Num.Text), i)
            item.[Day] = dateValue.ToString("ddddddddd")

            myList.Add(item)

        Next

    ElseIf month = 4 OrElse month = 6 OrElse month = 9 OrElse month = 11 Then

        For i As Integer = 1 To 30

            Dim item As [myClass] = New [myClass]()
            item.[Date] = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", i.ToString("00"), Mth_Txt.Text, CurrentYear.Text)
            Dim dateValue As DateTime = New DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear.Text), Convert.ToInt32(Mth_Num.Text), i)
            item.[Day] = dateValue.ToString("ddddddddd")
            myList.Add(item)

        Next

    ElseIf DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) Then

        For i As Integer = 1 To 29

            Dim item As [myClass] = New [myClass]()
            item.[Date] = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", i.ToString("00"), Mth_Txt.Text, CurrentYear.Text)
            Dim dateValue As DateTime = New DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear.Text), Convert.ToInt32(Mth_Num.Text), i)
            item.[Day] = dateValue.ToString("ddddddddd")
            myList.Add(item)

        Next

    Else

        For i As Integer = 1 To 28

            Dim item As [myClass] = New [myClass]()
            item.[Date] = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", i.ToString("00"), Mth_Txt.Text, CurrentYear.Text)
            Dim dateValue As DateTime = New DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear.Text), Convert.ToInt32(Mth_Num.Text), i)
            item.[Day] = dateValue.ToString("ddddddddd")
            myList.Add(item)

        Next

    End If

    GridView1.DataSource = myList
    GridView1.DataBind()

    'code that generates GridView2 (SQL data)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim DateTB As New DataSet

    Dim DateCmd As String = "select ScheduleDate FROM [SQLIOT].[dbo].[ZEPB_PreventiveDateSchedule] " _
                            & " where line_desc = '" & LineList.SelectedItem.Text & "' and process = '" & ProcessList.SelectedItem.Text & "' " _
                            & " and machine = '" & MachineList.SelectedItem.Text & "' and Step = '" & StepList.SelectedItem.Text & "' " _
                            & " and inspection = '" & InspectionList.SelectedItem.Text & "' and  specification = '" & SpecificationList.SelectedItem.Text & "' "

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(DateCmd, Conn)

    cmd.Connection = Conn

    Conn.Open()
    da.Fill(DateTB, "TempStore")

    Dim dvgroup As DataView = DateTB.Tables("TempStore").DefaultView

    GridView2.DataSource = dvgroup
    GridView2.DataBind()

    Conn.Close()

    'code to cross-reference and auto tick checkbox - Currently empty...
```

Currently I'm a little stuck on how to code the cross-reference part.

Also, a little explanation on how the program works.:

1. When 1st load there are a bunch of drop down lists where user picks their data, along with the month.
2. With a click of a button, the calendar GridView will load with full dates based on the month selector.
3. User will click on any of the GridView's row checkbox to upload the information from drop down list, along with the selected date from GridView to SQL database.

Hopefully this gives some more context to my question.

Comment: Why do you need to have to grid views for this?  Get the data from the DB, parse it as required and display the results.  There is absolutely no reason to be using a second UI component to calculate a boolean value

Comment: Never actually used parse before. From what I read in layman's term it converts string to integer. Question is, how would that apply in this scenario?

Comment: Ummm.... think you might have mis-unstood what I was meaning.  I was't meaning calling any Parse() function to do any sort of type conversions, more just you interrupt the data.  Sorry, maybe a bad choice of wording on my part

Comment: What I was meaning, you've got a 2 data sets of some nature.  Iterate over one to calculate the values on the other without the overheads of UI components.

Comment: All that aside though, there a few other things here you may need to resolve before getting too far into the data interrupting.  Seems odd that you can't do all this via a single sql query and really you need to look at parameterizing your query.  Security issues aside, it makes you're life a whole lot easier

Comment: there's only one SQL query right now on GridView2. GridView1 have no SQL query whatsoever in the code, other than the insert/delete query I mentioned.

Comment: Maybe it'll make more sense if I show the full code for GridView1. Word of warning, its a little long.

Comment: First grid even with un-bound check boxes should still persist and remember checked boxes, and survive post-backs. This assumes that you ONLY load the grid on first page load (so in on-load even you check if IsPostBack=False, and in that code stub load up the first grid(. Additional post backs thus should not re-set the check boxes. They only would/should re-set if you re-binding and re-loading that first grid each time and you should not. However, it not all that clear why each date in the calendar does not have a check box and you use that? (not quite convinced of the why of 1st grid).

Comment: And I don't see why you could not create the calendar, and load that data into that calendar? You need 7 columns x say 6 rows tops. This calendar would thus potential display a few days from the previous month at start, and same at end. So you query against that database, and then loop to fill out the calendar, and pluck out data as you display the calendar. So your code to fill out + create the calendar can also in that loop pull/check for data in each date - and render that too.